Fibonacci and matrix modular exponentiation
I'm interested in a few problems that are related enough that I decided to put them all in one question.

What are the fastest known algorithms for finding large Fibonacci numbers modulo $p^k$, and modulo $m$ in general?
What are the fastest known algorithms for finding $A^n\pmod{p^k}$ where $A$ is an $r\times r$ non-singular matrix with integer entries? Consider $r=O(1)$.
Regarding the setup in problem 2, how can we bound the period of the sequence $I,A,A^2,A^3,\dots$ modulo $p^k$?

The relationship between problem 1 and problem 2 comes from the fact that
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n$ produces Fibonacci numbers. Any literature regarding these questions would be much appreciated.

For the third question see this Math stackexchange question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292620/exponent-of-gln-q

AFAIK 1) comes down to a special case of 2), and the best known for 2) are essentially the square-and-multiply algorithms based on the binary expansion of $n$ (which work just as well for finding matrix powers as for finding scalar powers).

@StevenStadnicki Great, I was just wondering if there are any tricks with Fibonacci identities that might give you a faster algorithm for 1

By the way, the matrix in this question is wrong. The zero is supposed to be on the main diagonal.

Cayley-Hamilton gives a useful optimisation for question 2 when n is large enough.

Yes, there is faster than doubling for 1. Look for "Pisano periods" in Wikipedia or projecteuler for exemple.

For modulo 2 I know a very fast algorithm that just reads the bits of $n$...

@PeterTaylor How do you use Cayley-Hamilton for 2)? Polynomial division by the characteristic takes time $O(n)$ AFAIK; the squaring method is $O(\log n)$ which is AFAIK asymptotically optimal because it literally takes you that long to read the input $n$...

@StevenStadnicki, square and multiply polynomials in the quotient ring. The exponent isn't the only variable: you've also got the size of the matrix, and multiplying $k\times k$ matrices is more expensive than multiplying in a degree $k$ quotient ring.

@PeterTaylor That makes perfect sense; thank you for the explanation!

For Q1, you may like to check Fiduccia algorithm and a more recent paper A Simple and Fast Algorithm for Computing the $N$-th Term of a Linearly Recurrent Sequence.
This is also applicable to Q2 (directly for companion matrices) since Cayley–Hamilton theorem implies that powers of a matrix represents a linear recurrence sequence itself. One may also compute the matrix Jordan form to reduce the question to computing powers of eigenvalues (i.e., zeros of the characteristic polynomial).
For Q3, the period modulo $p^k$ can be computed as explained in paper Linear recurring sequences over rings and modules. When $k=1$ and the minimal polynomial
of degree $d$ is irreducible, the period is known to divide $p^d-1$.
